# Count distinct values in excel with criteria on another column

Tags: excel, distinct, countif

I need a formula to count distinct IDs from a table, based on Point Of Sale name with a wildcard, eg I need to find all distinct IDs from the table below, titles of POS of which contain word "China*". The result must be 4 (3333,4444,5555,1010).

[image: table]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works fine, but I need a faster way to handle 100000 rows

{=SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("China*",A2:A10),0)>0,1/COUNTIF(B2:B10, B2:B10),""))}

Answer (score 1):

It's widely known that Frequency is much quicker. So if your IDs are numeric, you can use

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("China",A2:A10)),B2:B10),B2:B10)>0))
```

which must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

If the IDs are non-numeric you have to use:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("China",A2:A10)),MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0)),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B1))>0))
```

or similar.

[See support article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)